# PHP method that is called by ajax is including object type information that is messing up ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mongodb, codeigniter

**Background Information**

I have a PHP / Codeigniter web application that provides CRUD functionality to documents living in a mongo database.
I have ajax code in the front end that call methods to query data from the database to fill in drop down lists in my forms etc.

**Problem**

In my ajax calls, I've been having trouble looping through the data that is returned and I think it's because the data includes object meta data.

For example, please consider the following ajax code:

```
 39         $.ajax({
 40               url:"<?php echo site_url('site/sitelist');?>",
 41               type:'POST',
 42               dataType:'json',
 43               success: function(res) {
 44                     //loop through results
 45                         console.log('this is sre:'+ res);
```

When I try to manually navigate to http://myserver/myapp/index.php/site/sitelist this is what I get back at the top of the page:

> object(MongoCursor)[19]

**Code**

This is what my controller looks like:

```
    public function sitelist()
    {
            $params=array();
            $sitelistdocs = $this->site_model->get_sites($params);            
            //echo(json_encode($sitelistdocs));
            //return json_encode($sitelistdocs);
    }
```

And the model looks like this:

```
    public function get_sites($filter)
    {
            $collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('site');
            $result = $collection->find($filter);
            return iterator_to_array($result);
    }
```

**What I've tried**

As you can see, I've commented out both lines in the controller that might be responsible for printing / returning the meta data... but it's still returns it. 
When I enable just the echo statement, it correctly displays the json array... but prefixes it at the top with the cursor(?) or mongo object information.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I didn't include the mongo library that I'm using... but I can if you think it's relevant.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

In case it helps, I've pasted the mongo library I'm using here: 
http://pastebin.com/StayKTre

And the config file that's referenced in the library can be seen here: 
http://pastebin.com/jghz77US

**EDIT 2**

Here's some output from my console in Chrome to prove that the errors are related to the object meta data:

> (
>   **object**(*MongoCursor*)[*19*] )

that's associated the following error message:

```
VM1873:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: and... I'm an idiot.  I had my vim screen split into three... and the code in the model that you see pasted above wasn't actually saved ... but I thought it was.  once i saved the file... it "just" started working. lol.  Sorry for the noise.